# JQuery onclick target (this li span)

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have this html:

```
<div id="homepage-side-nav">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="cell"><a href=""><img src="images/home-btn1.gif" alt="" /><span>Link </span></a></li>
        <li class="cell"><a href=""><img src="images/home-btn2.gif" alt="" /><span>Link </span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to target the span of the li that I've clicked on.

Here's the code:

```
 $("#homepage-side-nav .cell").click(function(){

       $(this).animate({width:'225px'},200).css("background-color","#e5e6e7");

       $(this).mouseout(function() {

          $(this .span).hide();

        });

  });
```

There's a problem here where I need to animate the span and not the li that I've clicked on ... How can I get it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead.

HTML

```
<div id="homepage-side-nav">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="cell">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/home-btn1.gif" alt="" />
                <span>Link </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="cell">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/home-btn2.gif" alt="" />
                <span>Link </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#homepage-side-nav .nav .cell").click(function(){
    $(this).find('a span').animate({width:'225px'},200).css("background-color","#e5e6e7");
    $(this).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).find('a span').hide();
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4kfwha44/2/

Note about your original HTML/JS:
- The first selector you have `$("#homepage-side-nav .cell")` doesn't actually attach the click event properly because the *cell* class is not a child of the div with ID *homepage-side-nav*.

Comment: That's for hiding but how can I expant the SPAN on the LI I click on?

Comment: Right now this "$(this).animate({width:'225px'},200).css("background-color","#e5e6e7");" is expanding the LI that I'm clicking on ... I need to target the SPAN of the LI I click on

Answer (score 1):

You are to go to the specific item:

```
$(this).find('span').animate({width:'225px'},200).css("background-color","#e5e6e7");
```

This way you get the `this` and go to the inner element `span`.

Doc: https://api.jquery.com/find/